# How do I add multiple fish functions in a single script?

Tags: linux, alias, fish

I'm trying to shift to fish from zsh. As I've seen, load time of fish increases if I use **alias**. So I'd like to convert all of my alias into functions, but the thing is creating a function script for every alias is a bit hectic. So how do I add those alias in a single function script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based this [Stack Overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090308/4957508) by [ridiculous_fish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441328/ridiculous-fish), I would suggest creating a file under `~/.config/fish/` with the functions defined in them, then add a line to source that file in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file.

Example contents of `~/.config/fish/all-my-functions.fish`:

```
function example-function1
  ls -l $argv
end

function example-function2
  ls -a $argv
end

# continues as needed ...
```

and the line for `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
source ~/.config/fish/all-my-functions.fish
```

Alternatively, you could define all of the functions directly into your config.fish file.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the `alias` command in Fish is simply a shortcut to create a function with a little syntactic sugar.  E.g.

```
> alias ls "ls -lh"
> functions ls
# Defined via `source`
function ls --description 'alias ls ls -lh'
 command ls -lh $argv;
end
```

Perhaps it's the overhead of the functions being created/loaded that is creating your slowdown.  In that case, putting them all into a monolithic file that is (still) loaded at startup likely isn't going to help.

There are several simple solutions that don't even involve modifying your `config.fish`:

- For each alias, simply `funcsave <aliasname>`.  This will save the function to `~/.config/fish/functions`.  *This is really the right way to do it*, IMHO, since functions in that directory are [loaded on demand](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#autoloading-functions), not at startup.  This will give you the fastest shell start-up time.

  For example:

  ```
  > alias ls "ls -lh"
  > funcsave ls
  > ls -n ~/.config/fish/functions/
  -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 100  95 Aug 18 14:30 ls.fish
  ```

  Again, this file isn't even touched at startup -- It's "lazy loaded" when needed.  When you call `ls` for the first time in a session, Fish will execute the `ls` function in `~/.config/fish/functions/ls.fish`.

  Also, it's only necessary to `funcsave` on *existing* aliases.  When defining a new alias, just use `alias -s` to automatically create the lazy-load function file in `~/.config/fish/functions`.
- *Edit/Update*:  You mentioned wanting this to be as easy as possible, so here's a quick command-line that can automate the saving of all of your alias functions.  Once run, you should see the corresponding file for each alias in `~/.config/fish/functions` and you can remove the existing aliases from your startup.

  ```
  for f in (alias | awk '{print $2}'); funcsave $f; end
  ```
- If you really do want to create one monolithic file for your alias functions, and you don't mind the increased startup time (regardless of how much or little it is), then I still wouldn't modify `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.  Just create that file in `~/.config/fish/conf.d` and it will be read as part of the startup automatically.

  Whenever some instructions say to modify your `config.fish`, consider using a file in `conf.d` instead.  It allows you to more easily see (and modify) what each part of your startup config is doing, without mucking through a single `config.fish`.